# Why pause() function prevents seeing console output in C?

Tags: c, linux, function, pause, unistd.h

I'm a little bit confused how does the function pause() works in the sense of calling order. For example:

```
int main(){
     printf("Start\n");
     pause();
     printf("Finish\n");
}
```

I was expecting to get output "Start" before pause, but program just immediately pauses instead. Please, explain why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `fflush(stdout);` before the `pause();`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your terminal emulator doesn't apparently flush standard output on every newline. You can manually flush it with [`fflush(stdout)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) if you want to see the output immediately:

```
int main(){
     printf("Start\n");
     fflush(stdout);
     pause();
     printf("Finish\n");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem. I'm using PuTTy to learn, didn't think that problem might be there. Thank you !

Comment: I wouldn't have thought this would happen with PuTTY, but I guess it depends what you are connecting to. The standard I/O routines are supposed to use _line buffered_ output by default unless they can tell (or think they can tell) that the output is not going to a terminal. (There are some programs for Windows that emulate a terminal using pipes where this is a problem, because the standard I/O routines think the output is going to a pipe and so are fooled into using _fully buffered_ output instead of _line buffered_ output.)